# Episode of Poltergeist: The Legacy (1996-1999) with the worst witness ever

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

Here is a link to "How to ask a Good Story ID Question".

[How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

And the thought has occurred to me that it might be a good idea for the suggestions on how to ask a good ID question to give the story of the worst fictional witness ever, as a really, really, really  bad example of omitting a very important detail.

As I remember, in an episode of *Poltergeist: The Legacy* (1996-1999), which was set in then contemporary times, members of the supernatural-evil-battling organization The Legacy traveled from their local HQ or "house" in San Francisco to a foreign destination.

There a woman was attacked by a man.  As a victim, it is natural that she was upset and unable to think clearly.  But as a associate of the San Franciso Legacy house she should have considerable experience with frightening events and should have learned to pull herself together and calm down.

She described one very important and unusual detail to the police and her team members, the man was wearing medieval style clothing.  (I'm not certain how accurate the style was for the specific medieval era, but that is a different matter).

But she omitted mentioning the strangest and most noticeable aspect of her attacker - he was wearing a crown!

Of course the protagonists were eventually able to deduce the totally unexpected identity of her attacker - someone you'd never expect to meet in the late 20th century - without her mentioning that vitally important detail.

So naturally naming the episode of *Poltergeist: The Legacy* (1996-1999) where someone omitted mentioning such an obvious and vital clue would be a good idea to anyone who ever wants to use it as a bad example to be avoided.

So if any fan of *Poltergeist: The Legacy* (1996-1999) reads this, feel free to answer and show your expertise on that series. But don't reveal the identity of the attacker, which was one of the most surprising reveals in all of television history.

But if you don't already know the episode don't bother to look it up, because I found it and will reveal it in an answer shortly.  Anyway, the first online mentions I found were my own comments about that episode.

Comment: is this a question? Seems like a meta post. If it is a question - it could use some editing

Comment: Is your question (that you plan to self answer) asking for the identity of the attacker in a specific episode of the referenced show? If so, you should make that more clear. Also you may want to switch from 'story-identification' to 'character-identification'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  no question asked, just comment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment about the crown, I'm assuming you are referring to Episode 63, "[The Last Good Knight](http://legacyweb.com/episodeguide/63_thelastgoodknight.htm)".

> Kristin and her driver arrive at the Well of Souls, a circular depression surrounded by a low rock wall, with a slab carved with Templar crosses. Kristin calls for her father, and even though she had told him to wait the frightened driver quickly drives away. As soon as he is out of sight Kristin is confronted by a tall, angry blond man with a dirty face, dressed in robes and a crown. Speaking in French he demands the map; Kristin insists she didn't bring it, and he grabs her around the throat and demands more forcefully. She tells him to go to hell. Just then he sees her crucifix; this seems to anger him and he strikes her to the ground. He stands over her as she lies there unconscious.

As you request, I will not state the attacker, but I found it via a search for `poltergeist the legacy "crown"`, which also brings up your post about the "[worst witness](https://moviechat.org/tt0115317/Poltergeist-The-Legacy/58c760716b51e905f67fd97c/The-Worst-Witness)".

Comment: :) I know you said not to identify it, but I'm somewhat confused as to why one would post an ID question, without also posting the answer, if you didn't want an ID.

Comment: I wanted to give a fan of the show a chance to show their knowledge of it.  But apparently you searched for the answer instead of remembering it.

Comment: @m.a.golding So, what *was* the question?